# Laravel webhook route returning 405 error - ideas?

Tags: laravel, webhooks, mailchimp

I am setting up webhooks for my laravel 5.3 site in response to events from mailchimp.

I am setting up the callback in MailChimp but Mailchimp keeps showing a 405 error.

Here is what I have on my site:

For verifycsrftoken middleware:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */


    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'zoom/*',
        'mailchimp/*',

    ];
}
```

By the way, stripe webhooks are working just fine...

In web.php

```
// zoom webhooks
Route::post(
    'mailchimp/webhook',
    'MailchimpWebhookController@handle'
);
```

In my Controllers folder (same place where the Stripewebhook controller is) here is my MailchimpWebhookController

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class MailchimpWebhookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle a Stripe webhook.
     *
     * @param  array  $payload
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handle(Request $request)
    {
        // Handle The Event

        return Response('My Mailchimp Webhook Handled', 200);
    }
}
```

In Mailchimp I am specifying callback as `https://somesite.com/mailchimp/webhook`

Just can't figure out why this isn't working... I have cleared cache, route, nothing is working. If I do this:

```
Route::get('mailchimp/webhook', function()
{
    return Response('My Mailchimp Webhook Handled', 200);
});
```

Then it works. But this won't:

```
Route::post('mailchimp/webhook', function()
{
    return Response('My Mailchimp Webhook Handled', 200);
});
```

So somehow seems the post method is somehow tripping this up. But like I said, stripe webhooks work just fine...

Maybe something obvious?

thanks

Comment: I have no experience with Mailchimp and webhooks. But you have to be sure that Mailchimp is indeed making a `POST` request to `mailchimp/webhook`. Are there any logs in the Mailchimp dashboard? You might also want to check the access log of you server software, [Nginx](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/) [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP 405 - Method not allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#405)

> A request method is not supported for the requested resource; for example, a GET request on a form that requires data to be presented via POST, or a PUT request on a read-only resource.

MailChimp send GET request, but you are wait for POST.

Maybe GET route will help.

```
Route::get(
    'mailchimp/webhook',
    'MailchimpWebhookController@handle'
);
```

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize that Mailchimp requires a POST and GET method on the callback (GET only used when setting up the webhook in Mailchimp as I just read!)